# Flutter Constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying find out why my code includes this code
`const MyListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);`  whilst all the youtube tutorials am following don't.
For example my code runs like this

```
  const MyListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

but the tutorial am following the code doesn't include

`const MyListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);`

I am currently working with `Builder` and I don't know how to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Key` property is add newly to flutter, it is use to pass a key to your Custom widget in order to use it multiple time and can differ from each other. So it would not a big deal if you delete that line.